# How to validate DTD against XML in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I validate DTD against a particular XML in Node.js?

I have an endpoint that contains DTD for each XML payload but trying to find a good solution that can be schema validated with Node?

Comment: There are many npm modules that do this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xsd-schema-validator
https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxml-xsd

Comment: @Subin yes but is there DTD validation? DTD is written in SGML syntax which is different to XSD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old post, but now we can do it with [Node-Libxml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libxml)
So bad libxmljs can't