# NodeJS - XML Parser with DTD

Tags: node.js

Are there any packages for parsing XML files with DTD in nodeJS. Please note, DTD validation is important. I have checked and tried few packages from npmjs.com website but none of the xml parser validates dtd. There are few dtd validation packages as well but then these does not parse xml.

Comment: Already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485223/how-to-validate-dtd-against-xml-in-node-js

Comment: Is this an ancient tech? Even the http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp link doesn't work. I don't think anybody would bother to write a DTD validator these days. Why don't you just use another script running as a service?

Comment: Thanks Cernal Eker - I think you have not read the question. I am not after a dtd validator - I am after a xml parser that parses XML files which contains a DTD reference.

The link you provided does not work - since the website is down.